# Why does SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX suppress division by zero as well?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, divide-by-zero

It seems that `SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)`, suppresses division by zero.

Code to reproduce:

```
SetErrorMode(SetErrorMode(0) | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX); // Comment out this line and an error dialog will appear.
int a = 5;
printf("%d", 1/(a-5));
```

Why is that? From the name I assume it should suppress only General Protection Fault, which has nothing to do with division by zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MSDN reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The system does not display the Windows Error Reporting dialog.

This means that when you set the flag, it suppresses *all* error dialogs.

Comment: OK, thanks. The name made me assume it was only about access-violations and such.

Comment: @sashoalm There are many things in the Windows API that has evolved quite a lot over time, so their initial meaning may no longer apply. Always check the MSDN reference pages if there is anything you're unsure about.